# How do I refresh repository listing on Coderwall to account for deleted repos?

Tags: github, coderwall

I have an account on Coderwall, and it lists GitHub repos that I deleted long time ago. As a result, all the links point to 404 pages on Github.

This happens on renaming repositories on GitHub as well. On Coderwall, they list it as 2 separate repos and one of them is invalid.

I couldn't find any way in the settings to delete a repository or refresh the repo list from GitHub.

Comment: What if you revoke and then relink?

Comment: I don't think there is any option to revoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to contact [Coderwall Support](http://coderwall.com/contact_us) as this is done manually and per account on their side.

When I contacted them they fixed the issue within a day.

Their reply to me:

> I've removed the old repo. Let me know if you need anything else changed.
>
> Best,
>
> Alyssa & the Coderwall team